# Parsing XML data into excel

Tags: excel, xml, powershell, parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file into excel. The XML file contains various information about different PCs and I need to be able to filter by hostname in excel. I have included a sample from the file here.

I apologize for including so much of the file, but I have no experience with XML and it looks like this file is not following a standard format, I'm wondering if there's any way to extract the info I need? I have no clue where to begin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ReportHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text7"><TextValue>Local Windows Users Report</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</ReportHeader>
<Group Level="1">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Field Name="SRVNAME1" FieldName="{GETDATABYPROPERTY.SRV_NAME}"><FormattedValue>ORGNAME</FormattedValue><Value>ORGNAME</Value></Field>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
<Group Level="2">
<Group Level="3">
<GroupHeader>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Text Name="Text5"><TextValue>Hostname:   HOST1</TextValue>
</Text>
</Section>
</GroupHeader>
</Group>
<Group Level="3">
<GroupFooter>
<Section SectionNumber="0">
<Field Name="OBJNAME1" FieldName="{GETDATABYPROPERTY.OBJ_NAME}"><FormattedValue>List Local Windows Users</FormattedValue><Value>List Local Windows Users</Value></Field>
<CrossTab Name="CrossTab1">
<RowGroups>
<RowGroup>
<RowGroup>
<RowTotal RowNumber="0">Administrator</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="1">Guest</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="2">AccounName1</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="3">AccounName2</RowTotal>
<RowTotal RowNumber="4">AccounName3</RowTotal>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroup>
</RowGroups>
<ColumnGroups>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnGroup>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="0">Fullname</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="1">Status</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="2">Disabled</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="3">Property1</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="4">Property2</ColumnTotal>
<ColumnTotal ColumnNumber="5">Property3</ColumnTotal>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroup>
</ColumnGroups>
<Cells>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>OK
</FormattedValue><Value>OK
</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Administrators</FormattedValue><Value>Administrators</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="0" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Degraded
</FormattedValue><Value>Degraded
</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>True</FormattedValue><Value>True</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Guests</FormattedValue><Value>Guests</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="1" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>AccounName1</FormattedValue><Value>AccounName1</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>OK
</FormattedValue><Value>OK
</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Event Log Readers,Users</FormattedValue><Value>Event Log Readers,Users</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="2" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>AccounName2 User</FormattedValue><Value>AccounName2 User</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>OK
</FormattedValue><Value>OK
</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Users</FormattedValue><Value>Users</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="3" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="0">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>AccounName3</FormattedValue><Value>AccounName3</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="1">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>OK
</FormattedValue><Value>OK
</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="2">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="3">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>Administrators,aaAdministrators</FormattedValue><Value>Administrators,aaAdministrators</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="4">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
<Cell RowNumber="4" ColumnNumber="5">
<CellValue Index="0"><FormattedValue>False</FormattedValue><Value>False</Value></CellValue>
</Cell>
</Cells>
</CrossTab>
</Section>
</GroupFooter>
</Group>
<GroupFooter>
```

Comment: you can try with Power Query https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/connect-to-an-xml-file-power-query-78bbe5b5-ebf2-4036-bdcb-72ea47f34ee3 or the FILTERXML function https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7. Might be a bit easier with the Google Sheets IMPORTXML function https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en

Comment: I think your choices are to either edit it so it is a well-formed XML, and then use an XML parsing routine (those mentioned by @Slai are two options); or process it as a text file with the usual text functions, or Regular Expressions in VBA.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld what do you mean by the “usual text functions”?

Comment: There are many that can be useful.  Just do an internet search for `Excel Text Functions` and/or `VBA Text Functions` to get a list.  I'd probably use Regular Expressions, but I'm familiar with them and find them simpler to construct.